# Selected menu Highlight ASP.Net Web Forms

Tags: css, asp.net, webforms

I have this code on my TruckData page:

```
<!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR -->
<div class="left side-menu" style="background: #99CCFF">
    <div class="body rows scroll-y" style="background: #99CCFF; margin-top: 50px; padding-top: 40px">

        <!-- Sidebar menu -->               
        <div id="sidebar-menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink_TruckData" runat="server" Text="Truck Data" NavigateUrl="~/View/TruckData.aspx" Font-Underline="false" style="font-size: 18px; color: black">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:black; background: #E8D73E"></i> 
                        Truck Data</asp:HyperLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink_MaintenanceRecord" runat="server"  NavigateUrl="~/View/MaintenanceRecord.aspx" Font-Underline="false" style="font-size: 18px; color: black">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:black"> </i>
                        Maintenance Record</asp:HyperLink> 
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink_MaintenanceSchedule" runat="server" Text="Maintenance Schedule" NavigateUrl="~/View/MaintenanceSchedule.aspx" Font-Underline="false" style="font-size: 18px; color: black">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="color:black"> </i>
                        Maintenance Schedule </asp:HyperLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:hyperlink id="hyperlink_Inspection" runat="server" text="inspection" navigateurl="~/view/inspection.aspx" font-underline="false" style="font-size: 18px; color: black">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="color:black"></i>
                        Inspection </asp:hyperlink>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- End div #sidebar-menu -->
    </div><!-- End div .body .rows .scroll-y -->
</div>
<!-- END SIDEBAR -->
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.row a:hover {
    background-color: #6699FF;
}

.row a:active {
    background-color: #;
}

.row a:visited {
    background-color: #;
}

.row a:selected {
    background-color: #63D130;
}
```

This is the output:

[image]

On the picture, only the glyphicon is highlighted. I want to highlight the whole. How can I highlight the whole Truck Data menu? In normal HTML it worked, but in ASP.Net, only the icon is highlighted.

Comment: its `rows` in your *DOM* and `row` in your *CSS* ?
and `<a>` is an `inline` element so you've to make it `block` for highlighting the whole area it covers.

Comment: or move the style to the `<li>`.